# Raspberry Pi SPI2 Interface Not Working with MCP251xFD CAN Interfaces

Tags: spi, can-bus

I am working on a project involving a Raspberry Pi (RPi) where I need to access three CAN interfaces via three MCP251xFD chips. I have set up these interfaces using the RPi's SPIs (SPI0, SPI1, and SPI2). While SPI0 and SPI1 work as intended and allow me to access the CAN interfaces(can0 and can1), I am facing an issue with SPI2. can2 simply wont show up.
I added these lines to the boot config:

```
dtoverlay=spi0-1cs,cs0_pin=8
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs,cs0_pin=18
dtoverlay=spi2-1cs,cs0_pin=0
dtoverlay=mcp251xfd,spi0-0,oscillator=20000000,interrupt=24
dtoverlay=mcp251xfd,spi1-0,oscillator=20000000,interrupt=26
dtoverlay=mcp251xfd,spi2-0,oscillator=20000000,interrupt=4
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to why SPI2 is not working in this setup? I already tested the hardware via the other SPI interfaces and it works.

**edit**; the dmesg error log:

```
[    2.493686] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-1013-raspi dwc2_hsotg
[    2.591136] pinctrl-rp1 1f000d0000.gpio: pin gpio2 already requested by 1f00074000.i2c; cannot claim for 1f00058000.spi
[    2.601990] pinctrl-rp1 1f000d0000.gpio: pin-2 (1f00058000.spi) status -22
[    2.616599] dw_spi_mmio 1f00058000.spi: Error applying setting, reverse things back
[    3.059504] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-1013-raspi xhci-hcd
[    3.098830] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-1013-raspi xhci-hcd
[    3.184127] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-1013-raspi xhci-hcd
[    3.223384] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 6.5.0-1013-raspi xhci-hcd
[    7.276617] dw_spi_mmio 1f00050000.spi: DMA init failed
[    7.279207] dw_spi_mmio 1f00054000.spi: DMA init failed
[    7.437189] spi_master spi0: will run message pump with realtime priority
[    7.448841] mcp251xfd spi0.0 can0: MCP2518FD rev0.0 (-RX_INT -PLL -MAB_NO_WARN +CRC_REG +CRC_RX +CRC_TX +ECC -HD o:20.00MHz c:20.00MHz m:20.00MHz rs:8.50MHz es:8.33MHz rf:8.50MHz ef:8.33MHz) successfully initialized.
[    7.449178] spi_master spi1: will run message pump with realtime priority
[    7.454061] mcp251xfd spi1.0 can1: MCP2518FD rev0.0 (-RX_INT -PLL -MAB_NO_WARN +CRC_REG +CRC_RX +CRC_TX +ECC -HD o:20.00MHz c:20.00MHz m:20.00MHz rs:8.50MHz es:8.33MHz rf:8.50MHz ef:8.33MHz) successfully initialized.
```

Comment: Check the kernel logs (dmesg command) for any error messages or warnings related to SPI2 or the MCP251xFD chip.